# Play Flash before wordpress site loading

Tags: php, flash, wordpress

I am a asp.net developer , but new to wordpress . I want opinion or expert advice in regard to playing a flash file before loading of home/Index page of wordpress site , for example in loading www.formula1.com  a flash file with sound is played , how can I get this feature done.Thanks

Comment: May I know why some people giving negative votes to this question

Comment: Upvoted - it should be noted Flash is indicating progress while html is preloading.  Once the HTML is loaded, there's a seamless transition between Flash intro and fully loaded html index page.

Comment: I want a flash into of the website with sound , where I should put it in if I am using wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not a WordPress specific question.  Do it first on an plain html build and once you have it working there, get it working in the same way on the WordPress build.

In WordPress your theme controls the front end of your site, so it would live in your theme folder.

If you're new to WordPress the best advice I can give you is, get it working in the most basic form possible first, and once you have that, look at finding the correct WordPress methods.

If you're not sure about how to make a flash file play as an intro to a website, while or before the website loads, ask that question outside of the WordPress context to get the answers you;re looking for.